# How to Print Rails Source Code?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, printing

I'd like to read the Rails 3 source code on printed paper (and preferably in color).

For example, [xv6](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/xv6-book/index.html) did a nice job printing their [code](http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/6.828/2009/src/xv6.pdf). It even has line numbers and an index. The only thing I would like to add is syntax highlighting.

Anyone know how any of this is possible?
Here are two possibilities I found:
1. The Listings Package (could this also generate other formats besides PDF, like HTML?)
ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/listings/listings.pdf o
2. Highlight (does it do indexing?)
http://www.andre-simon.de/

We could even add a rake task, print, that generates an up-to-date PDF.

Comment: That'd be a lot of wasted paper!

Answer (score 0):

I recomend you use highlight to turn the code into LaTeX and then use Listings to make it into a PDF, then print!